# Why __dict__ does not contain class member unless using derect initialization?

Tags: python, oop

I need to access list of class members in class methods specifically in `__init__()` function with intention of initializing them en masse. I tried to use `__dict__` and `vars(self)` but Unfortunately they return empty `dict` object, unless using direct initialization such as `self.y=5`. **The questions are; why that is empty and how can I initialize them at once, or essentially is variable `__dict__` suitable for bulk initialization?**

*thank you*

### sample code is like this:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self):
        print("inside __init__() :",self.y,self.__dict__)
    x=8
    y=9


p=P()
print(" y is: ", p.y)
print("and __dict__ is:",p.__dict__)
```

### output:

```
inside __init__() : 9 {}
 y is:  9
and __dict__ is: {}
```

- Python version: 3.8.5
- Tested Operating systems: windows 10, MacOS 10.15.7 and Linux CentOS 7

Comment: Do you mean "list of instance variables"? What data source do you use to initialize them en mass?

Comment: @tdelaney absolutely, instance variables are not in dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python class instances are dynamic - they don't have variables until you put them there (see note below). And they don't have any pre-knowledge of what those variables should be. Usually that's done by adding them one by one (e.g., `self.foo = 1`) in `__init__` or other methods in the class. But if you have a different source of variables, you can do it by adding to `self.__dict__`. Suppose I have a row from a CSV file and I want a class that is initialized by that row. I could do

```
class P:
    cell_names = ('a', 'b', 'c')

    def __init__(self, row):
        print("before", self.__dict__)
        self.__dict__.update(zip(self.cell_names, row))
        print("after", self.__dict__)

p = P((1,2,3))
print("attributes", p.a, p.b, p.c)
```

Outputs

```
before {}
after {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
attributes 1 2 3
```

There are other ways to initialize, of course. It depends on what the source of your "en mass" data is.

If you want to add all of the keyword arguments you could

```
class P1:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(kw)

p = P1(a=1, b=3, c=3)
print("P2", p.a, p.b, p.c)
```

(Note: You can use `__slot__` to predefine variables in a class. These bypass the instance dict)

Comment: Thank you indeed. Its very nice trick, using zip gets the job done. I think there should be some clearer ways as you mentioned. I try to send a spread dictionary variable into `__init__()` method as a parameter `**a` and then initialize instance variables with them without doing it one by one, because there are great amount of them.

Comment: Thank you once more, Your second edit and added code totally solved this problem

Answer (score 2):

`__dict__` only holds *instance* attributes. `x` and `y` in your examples are *class* attributes. `self.x` is an expression that could mean many different things; the actual result depends on which lookup succeeds first.

When you make an assignment like `self.x = 5`, then the value `5` is associated with the key `x` in `self.__dict__`.

When you try to get the value of `self.x`, the *first* thing that is tried is `self.__dict__['x']`. If that fails, though, it tries `P.x`. If *that* failed, it would check for `x` as an attribute in each ancestor of `P` in the MRO, until a value is found. If nothing is found, an `AttributeError` is raised. (This ignores the use of `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`, but is sufficient to explain how `self.x` can provide a value when `self.__dict__` is empty.)

Comment: you noticed to very useful concept with your rational description, Thank you indeed.